# Использование FileSystemWatcher для отслеживания расшаренных папок Shared Folder в виртуальных машинах

Tags: c#

Сделал FileSystemWatcher и он нормально работает в системе `C:\dir`, но задача стоит в работе с расшаренными папками в виртуалках, а наблюдение за Shared Folder не происходит, путь такой `\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\dir`

```
// Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
            {
                Path = Repository,

                // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
                // the renaming of files or directories.
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,

                InternalBufferSize = 25 * 4096,
                
                //Include Subdirectories
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,

                // All files (default). An empty string ("") also watches all files.
                Filter = "*",

                // Begin watching.
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
```

Comment: FileSystemWatcher для отслеживания расшаренных папок не походит. Запускайте слежку на том хосте локально, где эти изменения непосредственно происходят.

Comment: хорошо, но вопрос остается открытым, мне эти изменения нужны в виртуальной машине обработать а не в хосте. Есть идеи как наладить взаимодействие?

Comment: Запускать слежку на хосте, передавать данные на виртуалку, например по TCP

Comment: Хотя я мог наврать, говорят что работает https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231319/12888024, может дело в авторизации по сети или что-то подобное.